# Inverse Fourier Transform of a shape

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pCme.png)

---

> Hey guys I need some help to inverse fourier transform of this shape.
> The question is that:
>
> a) determine the minimum sampling density if this signal is sampled with "rectangular sampling matrix"
>
> b) If ahexagonal sampling matrix is applied to the same original signal,what
> coud be the minimum sampling density?
>
> I have some formulas to solve this question but first of all I need the original signal.I stuck in
> beginnig

---

Also this graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qoqX.png)

Comment: Split your shape in rectangles. Also integrating $e^{i \omega x}$ on a segment and hence $e^{i (\omega x+k y)}$ on a rectangle is easy.

Comment: I try but also I add another image what can i do for this?

Comment: I also added the formula of reconstruction BUT I CANT SOLVE please someone show the way